# Slider's thumb form change. C# XAML 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, slider

I'm making Windows 8.1 phone app using Visual Studio 2015 and C# XAML.

I want to change the slider's thumb to a "round" style, like below.
Can is be easily changed or not?

Please help me change the slider's style.

[image: I want to change Slider's style C# XAML 8.1]

Comment: Yes. It is possible with Blend. You an edit the control template using Blend tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following style for the slider thumb:

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle"
                                   TargetType="Thumb">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                        Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                    CornerRadius="4" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you Chirag Shar. I appreciate that.